# How to convert decimal literals into hex in C, 500 to 0x0500

Tags: c, hex, decimal, type-conversion

I have the following:
    int num=500;
    char text[8];

how do I make it so that text ends up being the hex 0x500, or 1280?

edit: i see that its pretty simple to make it text, like in some of the answers. But I need this text to be interpreted as a hex by C. So in reality it should be an unsigned hex int.

Comment: You don't mean `char *text[8]`, do you? That would be an array of 8 pointers.

Comment: yea that was wrong, just a string

Comment: In a production program, it's better not to have the value 0x500 stored as the integer 500 in the first place.  Integers are stored in binary, but can be considered to be just numbers; only strings are decimal, hexadecimal, or octal.  For a real-world problem, it's much more common to want to convert a string like "500" ({ '5', '0', '0', '\0'}) to an integer value, interpreting it as hexadecimal, for example by calling `strtol` with the `base` argument set to 16.  If you have an integer object with the value 500 that's meant to be 0x500, it probably indicates something has already gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
int num = 500;
char text[8];
sprintf(text, "0x%d", num); // puts "0x500" in text
```

This is assuming you on purposely didn't convert `num` to hexadecimal, if this wasn't on purpose this creates `text` with the integer converted to hexadecimal:

```
int num = 500;
char text[8];
sprintf(text, "0x%X", num); // puts "0x1F4" in text
```

Comment: yes im not converting 500 on purpose because it becomes 0x1F4 if I simply sprintf it. I need it to become 0x500 which is different from 0x1F4

Comment: @mugetsu: Then use my first solution.

Comment: but how would I be able to convert a hex text="0x500" into a decimal, 1280?

Comment: By using e.g. the strtol() function

Comment: ah i just found that the moment you replied. so it would be like strtol("0x500",&hex_int,10)   then hex_int=1280 ?

Answer (score 2):

There is an exercise in K&R, second chapter if I'm not mistaken, that asks to do this very thing.  If you are having difficulties I suggest you look up hexadecimal aritmetic on Wikipedia.