# Convert Decimal as hex

Tags: c, hex, decimal

I want to convert Decimal value as Hex format in C,

I am having Decimal value 22(0x16),i want to convert it as 0x22

How to convert it ?

Please help me.

Comment: Ignoring that Decimal 22 is hex 0x16; What programming language are you using, and what data types are you working with?

Comment: Could you clarify what value you are trying to express? Is it 22 in base 10 (0x16)? Or is it 34 in base 10 (0x22)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert decimal literals into hex in C, 500 to 0x0500](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448054/how-to-convert-decimal-literals-into-hex-in-c-500-to-0x0500)

Answer (score 0):

The decimal value "22" converted to hexadecimal (assuming a widespread notation) is "0x16", not "0x22".

Comment: s i know,But i need like this 0x22

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding the problem; is the value of "22" contained in a `char[]` or in an `int`?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.c4learn.com/c-programs/program-for-decimal-to-hexadecimal.html
Try this piece of code. Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int conv(int n){//n>=0;
    int hex = 0;
    int base = 1;
    for(; n ; n /= 10, base *= 16){
        hex += (n % 10) * base;
    }
    return hex;
}

int main() {
    int dec = 22;
    int hex = conv(dec);
    printf("%#x\n", hex);//0x22
    return 0;
}
```